# img tag not displaying image in react from api url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, graphql

Hi all this should be an easy fix, the  tag I have won't seem to display the Image from the API call. I have tried a few things but can't solve the issue.

Not sure if I made an error in the component or in the map function, anyways thanks in advance ‍☠️

the Sandbox link is here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-add-img-tag-mksoo

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const BlogCard = ({ coverPhoto, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <Link to={"/"}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <img src={coverPhoto} alt="" height={200} width={200}></img>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
export default BlogCard;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import BlogCard from "../Components/BlogCard";
const endpoint =
  "";

const QUERY = `
  {
    posts {
      id
      title
      slug
      coverPhoto {
        id
        url
      }
    }
  }
`;

const AllPost = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery("blog_posts", async () => {
    const response = await axios({
      url: endpoint,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: QUERY
      }
    });
    return response.data.data;
  });

  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return <pre>{error.message}</pre>;

  console.log(data.posts[1].coverPhoto.url, "hello");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Blog Posts Front End Development</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.posts.map((post) => (
          <BlogCard
            title={post.title}
            key={post.id}
            coverPhoto={post.coverPhoto}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllPost;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AllPost from "./Pages/AllPosts";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <AllPost />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coverPhoto is an Object which contains the id and url property so actual image is available at coverPhoto.url and it should work.

Replace your image tag in BlogCard with the following:

```
<img src={coverPhoto ? coverPhoto.url: null} alt="" height={200} width={200}></img>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have consoled the image url in `AllPost` component as,

```
console.log(data.posts[1].coverPhoto.url, "hello");
```

So the problem should be because you are excluding `.url` and also you need to handle if `coverPhoto` is `null`. Try the below code,

```
{coverPhoto !== null ? (
      <img src={coverPhoto.url} alt="" height={200} width={200}></img>
    ) : (
      ""
    )}
```

Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-add-img-tag-2-1-2023-forked-lddmlb

Answer (score 0):

```js
{coverPhoto ? (
      <img src={coverPhoto.url} alt="" height={200} width={200}></img>
    ) : (
      ""
    )}
```